# Background imagem table não funciona em outlook

Tags: html

Estou montando um email marketing, e quando coloco o html no outlook ele não aparece a imagem que está como bg de uma tabela, alguém sabe como forçar isso?

Parte do código que está com a img como bg:

```
  <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width='558' height='379' background="http://www.intercambioglobal.com.br/emailkt/harvard/logo-mid.jpg"  style="width:558px; height:379px; background-image: url(http://www.intercambioglobal.com.br/emailkt/harvard/logo-mid.jpg);">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Michel**, tente desta forma:

```
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.intercambioglobal.com.br/emailkt/harvard/logo-mid.jpg" color="#7bceeb"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="558" height="379" style="width:558px; height:379px;">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="http://www.intercambioglobal.com.br/emailkt/harvard/logo-mid.jpg">

            <!-- sua tabela original -->
            <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="558" height="379" style="width:558px; height:379px;">
                <tbody>
                     <!-- conteúdo da sua tabela -->
                </tbody>
            </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Eu tenho conteúdo que está posicionado sobre essa tabela, então se eu usar isso como td, o conteúdo vai ficar pra fora. segue o link.http://www.intercambioglobal.com.br/emailkt/harvard/emailkt.html

Comment: Opa, modifiquei a resposta! Sua tabela ficaria dentro de uma outra tabel que teria o `bg` num `<td>`!